# Is there a way to do disjoint reads of MPI_Bcast?

Tags: mpi

I have a program that uses `MPI_Bcast` to send control messages from a root rank to all other ranks. These control messages are comprised of two 64-bit values: the first of these is the header that tells the receiving rank what to do, and the second is a parameter of some kind.

For example:

```cpp
// Assume that comm is the communicator, root_rank is the rank of the root, and Header:: is the 
// namespace for the commands.
uint64_t message[2] = {Header::DO_SOMETHING, 5};
MPI_Bcast(message, 2, MPI_UINT64_T, root_rank, comm);
```

However, I've found myself in a situation where the parameter differs between ranks. Namely, I would like to be able to vary the "5" in the above example across ranks. Normally I'd use `MPI_Scatter` for this, but this seems wasteful in the situations where the parameter is shared across all ranks. In addition to this, the receiving ranks retrieve these messages inside a control loop, and so it isn't necessarily possible ahead of time to predict which of `MPI_Scatter` or `MPI_Bcast` was used.

What I'd really like to be able to do is to be able to retrieve the first broadcast value at the receiving ranks and then, depending on that, either call `MPI_Bcast` or `MPI_Scatter`. However, this doesn't seem to work if I restrict myself to just one MPI collective operation.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve just doing an `MPI_Bcast` followed by an `MPI_Scatter` or an `MPI_Bcast`?

I've tried to do this by using two separate non-blocking `MPI_IBcast`, but my OpenMPI seems to crash on that. I can (of course) get this to work by using multiple collective operations. I'm also familiar with the MPI performance guidelines which says that a `MPI_Scatter` shouldn't be slower than an `MPI_Bcast`, but in this instance I would have to do more work locally to always be able to use an `MPI_Scatter` (the buffer would need to be far larger, for example).

Comment: Assuming you broadcast most of the time, broadcast a "magic" value that means a scatter is needed.

Comment: I had thought about that: if that's the only solution, I guess this just means I need to accept that sometimes I'll have to send an extra 64-bits. Thanks!